# Slack API mark channel read 2020

Tags: slack-api

I have a Slack app to interact with Slack as the user.

I was able to retrieve messages and reply to messages, but one thing I cannot figure out is how to mark a message or channel as read.

The only API end-point I found was channels.mark (https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.mark), but it's deprecated.

How can one use the new Conversations API to move the read cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone lands here, the new API now has an endpoint (has for a while actually): https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.mark